# Present Perfect in the past time contexts

Tags: time-reference

"He soon became rich due to the good he had gained. But several years *have passed*, he married and became a merchant, richer than he was in the city." Can *have passed* be a correct choice? Maybe it can be possible in the past time contexts under some circumstances?

And there is one more dubious excerpt from the same source:"During the trip, a violent storm rose on the lake. And the ships *would* be sunk, but he realized in time: The king of the sea tribute demands." Is *would* a right choice here?

I am feeling that something grates on the ear in these both cases but I can't tell for sure if it was written by a native English speaker or it is just an awry translation from some language by a non-native.

Comment: I tried Googling those excerpts and nothing relevant came up aside from this question itself. What book/other source are the quoted passages from?

Comment: It doesn't look as if it was written by a native speaker - but you need to tell us where you found this.

Comment: @Quack E. Duck I was looking through the brief summary of J. Aldridge's "The Last Inch" on the site en.unansea.com. Below the article was the link to "The summary of Sadko". My question arose from it.

Comment: Typo - *have passed* where *passed* would have worked. Could all be in that tense, but not one sticking out. You found a typo!

Comment: @Yosef Baskin Thank you. What could you say of the second part of my question, that with "would"? I thought it should be "would have been sunk".

Comment: Yes, "would have been sunk" is clear, but *would be* brings it to life in a different way. It's okay. He worried and thought "The ships would be sunk!"

Comment: The present prefect is always related to the present AND the past. But your question is about would. "The king of the sea tribute" is off.